# Search substring in a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, search, substring

I am trying to find a particular string in a PHP array as below.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sku,qty,is_in_stock ) [1] => Array ( [0] => EBCDAA014MAS34B,149.000000,1 ));
```

I am preparing the above array as below and I am storing it in a variable called `$listing`

And I am using `array_find()` function to do so.

```
function array_find($needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($value, $needle)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$hello = array_find('EBCDAA014MAS34B', $listing);
echo $hello;
```

But still, I am getting the return as false. Can anyone kindly tell me which is the right way to do this?

Comment: Looks as though your reading a CSV using `file()`, you may be better off processing this file properly rather than continuing with this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is an array of arrays where your string is the first item in each of those arrays which will be `$value[0]`

Try changing this line:

```
if (false !== stripos($value, $needle)) {
```

To this line:

```
if (false !== stripos($value[0], $needle)) {
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/OIATZ)

Comment: That was so dumb of me! Thank you so much for the help. I'll Accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use **in_array()** PHP Function, see below example.

```
    $listing = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sku,qty,is_in_stock ) [1] => Array ( [0] => EBCDAA014MAS34B,149.000000,1 ));
in_array('EBCDAA014MAS34B', $listing)
```